# Powershell Stop-Process null param when calling in foreach loop

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have the following tiny PowerShell script that's meant to kill some certain processes on a remote machine:

```
$destPS = "mywebserver1"
$brokerPIDs = Get-Process -ComputerName $destPS | ?{$_.processname -eq "uniRQBroker" -or $_.processname -eq "uniRTE"}
foreach ($process in $brokerPIDs){
    $thisId = $process.ID
    Write-Host "Killing PID $thisId"
    Invoke-Command $destPS {Stop-Process $thisId}
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Id' because it is null.

As far as I can see, the pipeline shouldn't be interrupted by anything, so I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script block doesn't get the `$thisId` and that is set to null. So `stop-process` gives the error. You can pass the arguments to the script block like @Rynant mentions.

Since all you are doing is to get the processes and kill processes that match your requirement, move the commands into a script block and execute that scriptblock as whole using `Invoke-Command` on the remote box:

```
$script = {Get-Process -name uniRQBroker,uniRTE  | stop-process -passthru | %{write-host killed pid $_.id}}

invoke-command -script $script -computer $destPS
```

Comment: Thanks. I really like your compressed version of the script too, far fewer remote calls to slow the system down (it can be run over a high-latency link).

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the variable `thisId` to the scriptblock as an argument (`Invoke-Command` executes the scriptblock in a separate temporary session when running against a remote computer, hence local variables are no longer in scope). Try it as:

```
Invoke-Command $destPS {Stop-Process $args} -ArgumentList $thisID
```